# How to erase an element that is nested within a list which is nested within a vector

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator, hashtable

I'm building a hashtable using separate chaining using vector of a list of pairs as the data structure. I'm having some issues where I'm trying to erase a `pair` from the list structure nested within the vector. Here is a simple of the code http://cpp.sh/8cz4h

and here is the code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int myhash(const string & k) ;

int main()
{
   vector < list < pair <string, string> > > v;
   v.resize(15);
   string k = "foo";

   //I believe this will take me to the list element I want to iterate over
   for (auto &itr : v[myhash(k)])
   {
     if (itr.first == k)
     {
        //then delete the pair
        v[myhash(k)].erase(itr);
        break;
     }

   }


}

int myhash(const string & k) {
    return k.size() % 15;

}
```

with an error at the erase function saying it cannot match a list of pairs with pairs which makes sense to me, I know that `v[myhash(k)].erase(itr);` doesn't make a whole lot of sense, not sure how to fix it though.

something I think would do the trick is something like `v[myhash(k).at(itr)].erase(itr);` but I'm not sure how one can navigate to a certain spot in a list

thanks for anyhelp.

as a disclaimer I was chatting with a user on here yesterday with this problem and he came up with a solution here: http://cpp.sh/96na5 however this seemed a bit overwhelming to me and I have a feeling there is a simpler solution out there

Comment: See my answer. You can do that very simply without any loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `range-for` loop, you get the items of the list. `std::list` does not have a version of `erase` that accepts an item to be removed from a list.

Instead of using a `range-for` loop, use an iterator and a normal `for` loop.

```
auto& list = v[myhash(k)];
auto iter = list.begin();
auto end = list.end();
for (; iter != end; ++iter )
{
   if (iter->first == k)
   {
      //then delete the pair
      list.erase(iter);
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: @R thanks, can you explain real quickly why range based for loop causes an error?

Comment: @user3470987, I added a bit of explanation in the answer

Answer (score 2):

This can be done the following way

```
v[myhash( k )].remove( { k, k } );
```

Comment: does keeping the loop and then saying `v[myhash( k )].remove( itr );` work the way I think it would? which is deleting the pair the itr points to

Comment: @user3470987 Always it is better to use a standard approach instead of writing your own loop that to do the same that can be done in one line.